# ios app containers sync with icloud

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud-drive

I am building an app that contains its own iCloud container. The capabilities configuration is attached below.

[image]

Below is the key entry in Info.plist.

```
<key>iCloud.com.dearle.Ascert</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
  <string>Any</string>
  <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
  <string>Ascert</string>
</dict>
```

It is my understanding that anything I put into my app container should show up in the iCloud drive under a folder named Ascert and that I should be able to open the document in my app from the iCloud drive.

I have tried everything I can think of, unfortunately I am not very experienced with xCode so am unsure of where I am going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure your app needs known file types configured as well.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back to me so quickly.  Could you explain what you mean.  How would I do that?

Comment: Hm digging deeper, that may not be it at all. Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26947435/1214800?

Comment: @brandonscript   I gave that a go brandonscript, unfortunately no success. Just wanted to say thanks for trying.  XCode baffles me!!

Comment: @TonyDavidson As per my understanding of your question, The container does not display on you iCloud drive is it?

Comment: @Rakshith Nandish   yes that is correct Rakshith, I couldn't get my container to show up in the iCloud folder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as well, the setup you have done is correct. Try increasing the build number and version number before you run your code for the iCloud functionality. This worked for me. Apparently as long as these values are not increased the iCloud setup is not picked up

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't be visible in iCloud drive. It will be in iCloud / Manage Storage/ Container name.
To sync files between different devices with same Apple id, you use method startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462352/document-saved-on-icloud-drive-seems-not-to-be-downloaded-on-ios)